# How toget a list of POJOs with distinct HQL in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, distinct, type-safety

I'm trying to perform a query with the 'distinct' HQL clause in hibernate and get a List.  But, whenever I use 'ditinct'  I get a List of java objects instead of the POJOs which are returned without using 'distinct'.  Is there a good way to get the pojos instead of objects?

EXAMPLE that returns a list of POJOs as expected:

```
class myPojos () { ... (has some properties/fields) propOne, propTwo, propThree ...}
```

Inside a DAO

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.currentSession();

List<myPojos> myPojoList = s
                .createQuery( "select from " getPojoClass().getName())
                .list();
```

However,  adding a 'distinct' clause

```
List<myPojos> myPojoList = s
                .createQuery( "select distcinct mpl.propOne, mpl.propTwo, mpl.propThree from " + getPojoClass().getName() + "mpl" )
                .list();
```

...instead returns a List of objects.  So, I loose all the getters and setters of myPojos class and loose type-safetey.

Is there a way to do this and get a List to retatin getters/setteres & type-saftey?

Comment: is HQL a must?  check here (similar NHibernate issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318157/get-distinct-result-set-from-nhibernate-using-criteria-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following approach: `select p from Pojo p where p.id in (select distinct id from Pojo)`. You are performing the distinct in a subquery, letting to the main query just the selection of the ids already unique selected.

Comment: As soon as I add "p from Pojo p" to my select the objects returned are no longer POJOs

Comment: p is your pojo instance and not a field (in your question example your retrieve objects because you select the fields from your pojo)

Comment: Do you mean : List<myPojos> myPojoList = s                 .createQuery( Select new myPojos from MyPojos...

Comment: No, if you `select e from Employee e` you don't select properties from class `Employee` you will receive the instance `Employee` back. In your question you did a distinct over properties what is a bit different (resulting in this case in an array of `Object`s)

Comment: What Francisco is saying is that it is not the "distinct" that causes your result to be transformed into a List<Object[]>. It is the naming of properties in the SELECT clause which forces the results to be transformed as PROJECTION. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961048/setresulttransformer-in-criteria