# Hibernate criteria Using GROUP BY and RETURN ENTITY LIST

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to use `GROUP BY` in my criteria. I need to do this:

```
SELECT b FROM Book b GROUP BY volumeCode;
```

I have following code:

```
    Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Book.class);
    c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("volumeCode")));
    List<Book> result = c.list();
```

But this criteria returns only `volumeCode`s (a list of Strings). I need to get a list of `Book`s. So I tried to use Transformers:

```
    Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Book.class);
    c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("volumeCode")));
    c.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Book.class));
    List<Book> result = c.list();
```

This code returns list of null values. Is it possible to do that with criteria?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the projecton filters the amount of data retrieved, if you want more data, you should add those properties to the projection too.

Example:

```
c.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.property("id").as("id") )
    .add( Projections.property("descripction").as("description") )
    .add( Projections.groupProperty("volumeCode").as("volumeCode") ));
```

Now, the transformer does what it says "Alias to Bean", it does an alias match with the properties of your java bean "Book.java".

Edit:

Without the transformer, if the projection has more than one property, the result comes out like this:

```
for(Object[] item:criteria.list()){
    System.out.println( (String)item[0] ); //ID
    System.out.println( (String)item[1] ); //Description
    System.out.println( (String)item[2] ); //Volume code
}
```

Thats why you were getting the cast exception, about the transformer, try to match every alias with the property name of your java bean.

Comment: Hello Ziul, thx for your reply. With your advice I get List of objects but Java throws Exception when I try to cast any object from the list to the Book.

Comment: Ehm, I delete line with transformer O:-)... After adding this line back I still get List of null objects.

Comment: Thank you for editing your post. I don't wanna get only one property but whole object.  I need to get the same list of objects like after calling `SELECT b FROM Book b GROUP BY volumeCode` so the result should be List<Book>

Comment: Then you need to get the transformer working, just add every property of your Bean to the projection with a matching alias (same name for alias and property), and it will work.

Comment: When you `GROUP BY` volume code, shouldn't you also group by all the other properties, id and description? Or put them in some aggregation function?

Answer (score 5):

cz_Nesh.
sorry about my first answer.
i read Hibernate api and read some Hibernate source code i find that. 
if you use this code

```
session.createCriteria(EmpUserImpl.class).list();
```

it will return List EmpUserImpl.
if you use this code

```
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("company").as("company"))
            .add(Projections.property("name").as("name"))
            .add(Projections.property("company").as("company")));
        List list = criteria.list();
```

it will return List ,is not List EmpUserImpl   why?
i see the criterion's parent class CriteriaSpecification i find that .

```
public interface CriteriaSpecification {

/**
 * The alias that refers to the "root" entity of the criteria query.
 */
public static final String ROOT_ALIAS = "this";

/**
 * Each row of results is a <tt>Map</tt> from alias to entity instance
 */
public static final ResultTransformer ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP = AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE;

/**
 * Each row of results is an instance of the root entity
 */
public static final ResultTransformer ROOT_ENTITY = RootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE;

/**
 * Each row of results is a distinct instance of the root entity
 */
public static final ResultTransformer DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY = DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE;

/**
 * This result transformer is selected implicitly by calling <tt>setProjection()</tt>
 */
public static final ResultTransformer PROJECTION = PassThroughResultTransformer.INSTANCE;

/**
 * Specifies joining to an entity based on an inner join.
 *
 * @deprecated use {@link org.hibernate.sql.JoinType#INNER_JOIN}
 */
@Deprecated
public static final int INNER_JOIN = JoinType.INNER_JOIN.getJoinTypeValue();

/**
 * Specifies joining to an entity based on a full join.
 *
 * @deprecated use {@link org.hibernate.sql.JoinType#FULL_JOIN}
 */
@Deprecated
public static final int FULL_JOIN = JoinType.FULL_JOIN.getJoinTypeValue();

/**
 * Specifies joining to an entity based on a left outer join.
 *
 * @deprecated use {@link org.hibernate.sql.JoinType#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN}
 */
@Deprecated
public static final int LEFT_JOIN = JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN.getJoinTypeValue();
```

}

can you see the public static final ResultTransformer PROJECTION  ? it say that This result transformer is selected implicitly by calling setProjection()
is mean when you use criteria.setProjection,the result will not List EmpUserImpl,because ResultTransformer is change to "PROJECTION" from "ROOT_ENTITY".it will packaging by Projection(like select name,oid .. ).
so, if you want to return List EmpUserImpl you need set Projections.property("name").as("name").,(if you need name just set name).
this is my code .

```
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EmpUserImpl.class);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("company").as("company"))
            .add(Projections.property("name").as("name"))
            .add(Projections.property("company").as("company")));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EmpUserImpl.class));
    List<EmpUserImpl> list = criteria.list();
    for (EmpUserImpl empUserImpl : list) {
        System.out.println(empUserImpl.getName());
    }
```

it can work .  i hope it can help you.

Comment: I'm getting the list of entire objects. But all the fields are null. Do you know why that's happening?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use:

```java
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: @rayryeng I encounter the same problem trying to get `SELECT p FROM person p GROUP BY personId` using criteria but using setProjection it just convert it to sql equivalent of `select distint(personId) from person` and return list of personId wheres i need the whole person object and `List<Person> list = session.createCriteria("Person","p")
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);` return the list of person object. as for why and how hope this will help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961048/setresulttransformer-in-criteria)

Comment: Add this to your post. We didn't know why this helped you initially